# Send additional data to the server with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've to save a new `message` onto the server and also send additional data to it
I've the following code

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    messagethread_id: DS.attr('number')
});

// in controller

var msg = this.store.createRecord('message', {
    body: messageBody,
    messagethread_id: thread.id,
    token: this.get('token')
});

msg.save();
```

As you can see the token isn't defined on the model so it isn't sent to the server. I need to send it but I don't need to retrieve that in any situation.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing: why don't you define also token in your model? Then you manage it server-side; for example when the token is not needed, you set it to null; in the server you can check if it is null or not; of course then your server will have to answer to GET request also with the token attribute (but you simply set it to null too);

or you can define two different models: a Message Model and a MessageWithToken Model; and then use the first one or the last one depending if you need to send token or not;
also in this case you will have to manage things in your server.

Comment: Yes I could but that's not the answer to my question, thanks anyway!